# Decomposition of 3-dimensional mapping torus into connected sum

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

In the following article
https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/3Msurvey.pdf
Hatcher mentioned that there is only one prime
closed 3-manifold with infinite cyclic fundamental group, which is
$S^1\times S^2$.

This implies that the 3-torus $T^3$ can be decomposed as a direct sums of three $S^1\times S^2$. Is it true that $T^3=S^1\times S^2\# S^1\times S^2\# S^1\times S^2$?

This also implies that the 3-dimensional mapping torus $M^3$: $T^2 \to M^3 \to S^1$ (with $S^1$ as the base manifold and $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ as the fiber) can be decomposed as a direct sums of $S^1\times S^2$. How such decomposition is achieved?

In general, I would like to to know the decomposition of 3-dimensional mapping torus into connected sum. In particular the connected sum decomposition of a torus bundle $E^3$: $T^2 \to E^3 \to S^1$.

Comment: $T^3$ is covered by $R^3$. It follows that $\pi_2(T^3)$ is trivial. I guess it follows that $T^3$ is prime. Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: The torus $T^3$ is irreducible (hence prime) and thus can not be split into the connect sum you alluded to

Comment: The fundamental group of a cartesian product of spaces is the direct product of their fundamental groups.  On the other hand, the fundamental group of a connect sum of spaces is the free product of their fundamental groups.  So, the connect sum of copies of $S^2 \times S^1$ has a free fundamental group, not an abelian one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first part of this answer is merely an elaboration on Marc Kegel and T. Amdeberhan's comments, and addresses the question before the edit. As they say, $T^3$ is prime by virtue of being irreducible (a stronger condition) -- since $\pi_2(T^3)$ is trivial, every embedded 2-sphere is null-homotopic in $T^3$ and it follows that it bounds a ball. [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_manifold) may be helpful for you.

While it is true that $S^1\times S^2$ is the only prime closed 3-manifold with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ (and all infinite cyclic groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$), this does not imply that $T^3$ is not prime. (On the off chance this helps, note that $\mathbb{Z}^3$ is not a cyclic group).

In the language of Hatcher's paper, $T^3$ is a prime 3-manifold of type III: it is $K(\mathbb{Z}^3,1)$.  Note also that $T^3$ is a Seifert manifold, thus the following statement in Hatcher's paper is consistent with this:

> The only Seifert manifold that is not prime is $\mathbb{RP}^3\#\mathbb{RP}^3$, the sum of two copies of real projective 3-space.

I believe the edit of your question is addressed in the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8223/reducible-3d-torus-bundles).  Namely, torus bundles are irreducible, so they admit no nontrivial connected sum decomposition.

Comment: I am not sure that there is something called *the* infinite cyclic group (just as there is no *the* algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$). Given two infinite cyclic groups, you do not have a unique isomorphism between them.

Comment: Fair enough, I will edit.